# ¿no me pasa variables por ajax a php?

Tags: php, jquery

```
$.ajax({

        url: 'functions/envio.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {nom:$("#firstname").val()}

    });
alert($("#firstname").val());
    $(location).attr('href','checkout2.php');

}
```

en el php

```
 $_SESSION['nombre']=$_GET['nom'];
```

pero al realizar la accion me sale que no esta definida la variable nombre por lo cual no se esta enviando por ajax que puede ser

Comment: Sería más simple `var nom=$("#firstname").val(), url = 'functions/envio.php?nom='+nom;`. Dependiendo del content-type el valor de data puede que lo estés enviando como payload del body y no sería capturable por $_GET.

Comment: Se hace necesario ver la función completa que llama al AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que no este haciendo la serialización correctamente, puedes tratar usando param de jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Algo asi:

```
...
data: $. param( {nom:$("#firstname").val()} )
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Te puedo recomendar que le eches un vistazo a la documentación de AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), ya que como lo muestras en tu código, ejecutas la función ajax y luego cambias el location de la página. Debido a que AJAX por defecto es **asincrónico**, lo que significa que esta línea `$(location).attr('href','checkout2.php');` se ejecutará sin esperar que el llamado AJAX termine.

Igualmente puedo recomendarte que al momento de realizar una llamado AJAX, bloquees el botón que produce este llamado para que el usuario no lo presione varias veces.

Te muestro un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#send').click(function() {
  
    var name = $('#name').val();
    
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/",
      dataType: 'JSONP',
      data: { name: name}
    }).done(function( result ) {
      // Si la respuesta es correcta, entonces cambias el location
      //$(location).attr('href','checkout2.php');
      alert('Llamado finalizado');
    }).fail(function(msg) {
      // Sia la respuesta es incorrecta, emites un error al usuario
      alert('Error!');
    });
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<button type="button" id="send">Send</button>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta! Claramente esto es lo que tiene que considerar/modificar... Sería bueno adaptar el ejemplo de jsfiddle a la necesidad del autor. En particular, te quedó como JSONP, y creo que complica las cosas.

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar con esto...

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'functions/envio.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {nom:$("#firstname").val()},
        success: function(data){
            alert( $("#firstname").val() );
            $(location).attr('href','checkout2.php');
        },
        error: function(e){
            console.err(e)
        }

    });

}
```